# SQL Server record set temp table closing too early?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, asp-classic

When I run the SQL through SQL Server 2008 it works just fine. However when I add it to a classic ASP web page and then call it from there it seems to break. I am not sure what I am missing?

```
sql = ""
sql = sql & " DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)"

sql = sql & " DECLARE @temp TABLE ("
sql = sql & " DistID varchar(30),"
sql = sql & " FName varchar(30),"
sql = sql & " LName varchar(30),"
sql = sql & " RankID int, "
sql = sql & " PSV int,"
sql = sql & " ShipCountry varchar(30),"
sql = sql & " ShipState varchar(30) )"

sql = sql & " INSERT INTO @temp"
sql = sql & " EXEC  [dbo].[MSGGetList]"
sql = sql & " @List = N'" & request("report_type") & "',"
sql = sql & " @DistID = " & Session("DistributorID") & ","
sql = sql & " @BusCtrID = 1,"

' Autoship Filter Params
If request("autoship") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @FilterAutoship = '" & request("autoship") & "',"
Else
    sql = sql & " @FilterAutoship = NULL,"
End If

sql = sql & " @ItemID = " & request("item_id") & ","

' Order Filter Params
If request("orders") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @Orders = '" & request("orders") & "',"
Else
    sql = sql & " @Orders = NULL,"
End If

If request("minvol") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @MinVol = " & request("minvol") & ","
Else
    sql = sql & " @MinVol = NULL,"
End If

If request("minpostamt") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @MinPostAmt = " & request("minpostamt") & ","
Else
    sql = sql & " @MinPostAmt = NULL,"
End If

If request("startdate") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @DateStart = '" & request("startdate") & "',"
Else
    sql = sql & " @DateStart = NULL,"
End If

If request("enddate") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @DateEnd = '" & request("enddate") & "',"
Else
    sql = sql & " @DateEnd = NULL,"
End If

' Location Filter Params
If request("country") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @Country = '" & request("country") & "',"
Else
    sql = sql & " @Country = NULL,"
End If

If request("region") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @Region = '" & request("region") & "',"
Else
    sql = sql & " @Region = NULL,"
End If

' Rank Filter Params
If request("rankid") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @RankID = '" & request("rankid") & "',"
Else
    sql = sql & " @RankID = NULL,"
End If

'Do Not send list
If request("DoNotSend") <> "" Then
    sql = sql & " @Exempt = '" & request("DoNotSend") & "',"
End If

' Volume Filter Params
sql = sql & " @MinPV = " & request("min_pv") & ","
sql = sql & " @MaxPV = " & request("max_pv") & ","
sql = sql & " @MinGV = " & request("min_gv") & ","
sql = sql & " @MaxGV = " & request("max_gv") & ","
sql = sql & " @MinLBVRBV = NULL"
sql = sql & " SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + DistID FROM @temp"
sql = sql & " SELECT @listStr AS ToList"
stop
response.write(sql & "<br />")
Set rsToList = GetRecordSet(sql)


response.Write(rsToList("ToList"))
```

When I step through the code and look at `rsToList` it says:

> Operation not allowed when object is closed

Any idea what I am missing here ?!

EDIT:

```
Function getRecordset(strSQL)

        If Application("DebugSQL") Then
            Call WriteSQL(strSQL)
        End If

        'Create Database Connection
        Set FunctionDBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        FunctionDBConn.ConnectionTimeout = 180
        FunctionDBConn.Open(Application("DB_ConnectionString"))
        Set adoRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        adoRS.CursorLocation = 3
        adoRS.LockType = 4

        'Create Recordset
        adoRS.Open strSQL, FunctionDBConn
        Set adoRS.ActiveConnection = Nothing
        Set GetRecordset = adoRS

        'Close Database Connection
        FunctionDBConn.Close
        Set FunctionDBConn = Nothing

    End Function
```

Comment: Wrap it in a transaction?  Only a comment.

Comment: @Blam I have never used transactions, would that provide me a more detailed idea of what is going on?

Comment: I am not sure what is causing the problem.  A transaction might make it go away.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.100).aspx  Only a comment

Comment: Should look up "SQL Injection" and then stop contatenating data received from the client into SQL code but instead use parameterised queries.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones the site has a stand alone SQL injection that scrubs all user input from query strings, cookies and forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the @temp Table.  I added the functionality to the stored procedure and remove the temp table and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This error is usualy resolved by beginning the SQL batch with the statement:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Comment: this command helped me.
Not allowing the execution to return the number of lines affected, preventing the RecordSet from closing due to not knowing how to identify the number of lines returned, due to having more than one return due to the temporary table

Answer (score 1):

Can we see your GetRecordSet Method?

it sounds like your closing the connection in the method.
  you will have to wait until your done processing the record set before closing the connection.

Consider passing the connection into the method or making it a page level variable which can be closed outside the method.

Comment: I can provide it, but the GetRecordSet method works in over 100 other places.  Editing the OP now.

Comment: i would encourage you to take a look at this function http://www.w3schools.com/ado/showasp.asp?filename=demo_ado_getrows

Comment: I would like to not rewrite existing code if I can avoid it.  If GetRecordSet works in every other place it is called (100's of places) except for this place, that has to mean something else is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions

- if you don't want to create stored procedure then
  begin the sql batch with the following statements

> SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
>
> ```
> SET NOCOUNT ON
> ```

- you may put the sql statements in inside the stored procedure and call it